# Is there contains function in jsRender?

Tags: jsrender

Just want to list all roles. If a role has this user, it will be displayed differently.

Pass in json data contains an array `Roles` (the roles a user has) and another one called `AllRoles` (all role values)

```
{{for AllRoles ~roles=Roles}}
    {{if ~roles.contains(#data)}} // I made this up, but how to write this if???
        <a href="#" class="selected">{{:#data}}</a>
    {{else}}
        <a href="#" class="unselected">{{:#data}}</a>
    {{/if}}
{{/for}}
```

Can anyone help us? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{if ~roles.indexOf(#data)>=0}}
```